# Rendering `Title` and `Edit` columns title description

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, view, spfield, rendering

I'm working on SharePoint 2016 OnPremises. I created a view which renders the columns titles, as the `_layouts/15/ViewEdit.aspx` does. 
The result:
[image]

The original rendering is slightly different:
[image]

Where do the discriptions `(linked to item with edit menu)`, `(linked to item)` and `(link to edit item)` come from? I debugged the `SPField` items but was not able to find any reference.

Comment: Workaround: all 3 titles has different static/internal name, you can provide mapping accordingly in your script.

Comment: Thanks, I already thought about it but I'd like to know if there is a 'clean' way, since I need it multilanguage.

Comment: are you using JSOM or CSOM?

Comment: I',m using Server Api. As you suggested, I found the `AuthoringInfo` property in the `SPField` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fetch **SchemaXML** for field collection or field,

there is attribute called as `AuthoringInfo` holds descriptions `(linked to item with edit menu), (linked to item) and (link to edit item)`.

Refer below image for detail:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]